# Arrow[] moving on its own, from the wrong spot

Tags: plotting, graphics

I'm trying to animate a rotating arrow within a plot, and I'm seeing two issues I can't figure out how to resolve.

1) The arrow isn't originating from {0,0} as I have demanded.

2) The length of the arrow is changing as it rotates.

```
Animate[
 w0 = 1 - t;
 θ = π/2 - t π/2;
 Plot[{t, -t}, {z, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-2, 2}}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Black, Black}, ImageSize -> Large,
  Epilog -> 
   Inset[Graphics[{Orange, Thick, Arrowheads[Large], 
      Arrow[{{0, 0}, {Cos[θ], Sin[θ]}}]}]]], {t, 0, 1}]
```

If I try to set the origin of the arrow instead to Scaled[{0,0}], the arrow doesn't rotate (and is still in the wrong place) unless I also scale the destination.  Doing both of these, the arrow rotates but still not from the origin of the plotspace.  Further, this is a problematic method since I also want to stretch the arrow (at the endpoint) as the animation runs further (excluded in the MWE).

Edit: MMA 11.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use [`Inset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset), since that disconnects the coordinates of the [`Arrow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Arrow) from the coordinates of the [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot):

```
Animate[
    w0 = 1-t;
    θ = π/2-t π/2;
    Plot[
        {t,-t},
        {z,-10,10},
        PlotRange->{{-10,10},{-2,2}},
        PlotStyle->{Black,Black},
        ImageSize->Large,
        Epilog->{Orange,Thick,Arrowheads[Large],Arrow[{{0,0},{Cos[θ],Sin[θ]}}]}
    ],
    {t,0,1}
]
```

Comment: Nailed it, thanks.